# PHP CodeIgniter 404 on deploy

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Oooops I did it again.

**My site worked perfectly locally**

My development machine is a windows WAMP2 setup
My server is a CentOS 5.5 APACHE 2.2 PHP5 seup

I'm getting a 404 on the codeigniter site that I've deployed, and I really can't make out what's wrong, so please help me find the error.

It's the root url. I haven't set up dns so it's just the ip address of the server. It was showing the standard apache page before I uploaded codeigniter. I've looked over the config file, and it looks ok. Could it be a file permissions error? i have set chmod o+rw in the whole /var/www/html dir. the error_log in the httpd shows nothing

I've tried testing if it was the mod_rewrite module, but I created a test directory with a .htaccess file with RewriteEngine ON that didn't give me an error, so that can't be it.

In codeigniter I've set the log_threshold to 4 in the config, but I don't get any log messages, so I can't really make out if it's a pre-> codeigniter error, but I really don't think it is, as it's loading my Error view, still Why isn't there any log being written, what's it about?

Any help would be extremely appreciated as I'm running on fumes to get this working...

**Update**
Thanks to @jondavidjohn I have discovered that hitting the controller directly IE:

http://addr/index.php/GeoController/markers/

Will provide me with a controller specific error saying:

unable to locate your model "modelname"

**SOLVED**
Thanks to @jondavidjohn, and @timdream for giving me the clues to solve this one. It was a naming problem, I had filenames that were camelcased, and they can only be small from what I understand now, so the ROUTE was innefective in that it lead to Site, but should've lead to site although I had a Site.php I had to change it and the route to site.php

Comment: @Matt Asbury - yes, it was only on deploy that I got an error

Comment: What URL are you getting the 404 error on? Anything you forgot to change in config.php? Is your .htaccess file definitely readable by the web server user? Anything in the Apache error log?

Comment: @Matt Gibson - It's the root url. I haven't set up dns so it's just the ip address of the server. It was showing the standard apache page before I uploaded codeigniter. I've looked over the config file, and it looks ok. Could it be a file permissions error? i have set chmod o+rw in the whole /var/www/html dir. the error_log in the httpd shows nothing

Comment: are you getting a general 404, or the Codeigniter 404 ?

Comment: @jondavidjohn - it's the codeigniter 404 (my customized 404) AND THANK YOU ALL FOR BEING SO ATTENTIVE I really appreciate seeing so many participants.

Comment: this may sound like a stupid thing, but it has happened to me before, try adding a "/" at the end of our URL

Comment: @GerManson - thanks for the suggestion, didn't solve it unfortunately. When I try to go to the server addr. without / at the end it automatically puts on a /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you have the correct settings in `system/application/config/config.php`.. pay special attention to

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com";
```

Make sure you are putting in the root domain of your site, also check your routing config and make sure you have the correct default controller set in `system/application/config/routes.php`

Comment: to avoid any confusion I have now set up the dns, can it be the Routing? I only have the default controller, and that would be the same in the local and public environment wouldn't it?

Comment: possibly, i would just verify that it is correct, also are you getting the Codeigniter 404 or the apache 404

Comment: have you tried hitting your controller directly? `http://www.example.com/index.php/controller/index` ?

Comment: @johndavidjohn - that seemed to provide a clue!!!! Hitting the controller directly gave me a controller specific error saying that it could not find my model. What does that mean?

Comment: actual error verbage is always better than paraphrasing, what does the error say (copy/paste).

Answer (score 2):

I recently started using a fresh install of codeignitor 3.0 and had no problems on my dev server (Windows) then when I moved to my live server (Linux) I started getting a 404 error.

The reason for this is that in 3.0 you are meant to capitalise the first letter of your controllers/models and also the file name.

e.g.

class Test_model extends CI_Model {

Test_model.php

Hope this helps some people who end up here!

For reference:

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html

Answer (score 1):

`$config['uri_protocol']` could also play a part. It's default to `AUTO`, which looks for environment variable that contains the actual URL automatically.

I had a web app that fails when I switch to php-cgi from mod_php for my server. Changing the config to `REQUEST_URI` solves the issue. I found the valve by digging `phpinfo()` outputs, you could try to do that.

Comment: would it be safe to post a link to my app where I've output the phpinfo in the 404 page so you experts can also have a look at the phpinfo, or does it pose a safety threat to me?

Answer (score 0):

My first bet is that you were developing this and modified the `.htaccess` file.

HOWEVER, if you went from a Windows -> Linux system change (dev on Win, prod on nix) then you have to keep the Controller names in mind,  if a file on windows was "Home.php", and you used "home.php" in the config as your default route, then it will fail.. as there is no "home.php" file.

`Home.php != home.php`

Linux is case sensitive.  Check that out, it might be a simple thing but could cause snags.

Again I am just guessing due to lack of details.

Comment: thanks for the answer it was from win -> nix but I have been strickt about naming, I'm more prone to think it has something to do with the .htaccess file, but I did change the RewriteBase to be simply "/" and mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: post the **.htaccess** code just in case. If it is a codeigniter 404 page as you mentioned something is wrong with codeigniter then and not your apache setup.